# Make JavaScript Generated content appear on Search Engines, where content differs on a Single Page

Tags: seo, search-engines, javascript, search-engine-indexing, search

I have a PWA hosted on Firebase. On the main URL, like `example.com`, there's a lot of content that is generated by JavaScript.

At the same time, whenever someone accesses `example.com/?key=value`, where the `key` and the `value` are predefined, the JavaScript on the page reads the `key` and the `value` and accordingly removes the content generally shown on `example.com` and shows a different content.

The content differs with each `value` of the `key`.

With this, the website efficiently acts like a multi-page website, although it essentially has only a single web page.

The problem here is, I don't get the content displayed on these *sub-pages* visible on Google Search (or any other search engine). Is there any workaround on this?

---

The problem here is that I cannot generate a different webpage (an HTML file) for each of these *sub-pages* because the website uses only Front End Technologies, available with Firebase.

Comment: Despite what anyone says, SPAs are SEO suicide.

Comment: @JohnConde I can agree on that. But I realised this too late!